# Cannot pass int from JS to Chrome NPAPI plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, npapi

I'm using an NPAPI plugin that wraps an ActiveX control for use in Chrome/Firefox. Neither of which I wrote. It's an embedded ActiveX media player, which is bundled with a cross-browser plugin, that plays certain file types I need via a browser, that the normal players or  tags won't play (otherwise I'd use something else!)

I can create the player, and control almost all aspects of it from any browser, except when the Seek(position) command is called from JS in Chrome, the player doesn't seem to receive the value. For instance, if from JS I send...

```
GotoTime(30, 'myPlayer');

function GotoTime(position, player)
{
    console.log("TYPE: " + typeof position);
    o = document.getElementById(player);
    console.log("Seeking to:" + position);
    o.Seek(position);
}
```

In Firefox and IE, it will cue media to the correct position (30 seconds in this case) but in Chrome it seems to translate the value always as zero and play the clip from the beginning.

As you can see from the function, I'm confirming (in the console log) that I am actually passing a 'number' and not a 'string', but I think maybe the NPAPI plugin is interpreting it maybe as a float instead of an int or vice versa.

I'm 99% sure that this is an issue with the plugin and out of my control, I've contacted the supplier but they're not much help. Has anyone any ideas on things I can try?

By the way, the plugin in question is [here](http://www.umediaserver.net/umediaserver/BrowsersPlugin.html)

Many thanks

Comment: Related (Google dropping NPAPI Support from Chrome): http://thenextweb.com/google/2013/09/23/google-chrome-drops-netscape-plugin-api-support-to-improve-stability-will-block-most-plugins-in-january-2014/

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that, I did't realise. I guess ultimately, it's irrelevant whether it works or not then! I would still like to get it working in the meantime until a more future proof solution is found though.

Answer (score 0):

> maybe the NPAPI plugin is interpreting it maybe as a float instead of an int or vice versa

In the NPAPI you can get numbers passed to the plugin as [`int32_t` or `double`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/NPVariant) - it's completely unspecified which type you get.

Interpreting the argument as `0` is a typical symptom of not converting the number type when needed, so this is in all likelyhood an issue with the wrapping plugin.
They should convert to the required number type [depending on the variants `type`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14662724/168225).